# Where to find an official list of how each python keyword is implemented?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm learning python 2.7 and picking up the use of basic keywords from random bits of code or by searching questions here on stackoverflow. I know about the official python documentation, and found a list of keywords in it: [2.3.1. Keywords](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords). I also found similar information in wikipedia. Those are just lists of words without any explanation of how to use them.

I'm looking for a *clickable* list so that by clicking on *is* for example, it would take me to a description of how *is* is implemented. Is such a page in the official python documentation or anywhere on the internet?

Comment: Suggestion of a freely available book, which will be a much better resource for learning the language: [Dive Into Python 3](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/).

Comment: I came across that book in my searches, but as far as I can tell, that book doesn't have the answer to my question. My question is asking for something so basic that it would be a natural reference to have for any language. So, where is it for python?  

Other than finding answers to questions others have asked on this website, how would I go about finding, for example, the way that *is* is used in python? If it's in that book, where?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the list of keyword uses doesn't exist because different keywords are used in very different ways.

Here's a quick breakdown of the keywords from Python 2.7:

- [Operators and other Expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html):

  - `and`
  - `is`
  - `lambda`
  - `not`
  - `or`
  - `yield`
- [Simple Statements](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html)

  - `assert`
  - `break`
  - `continue`
  - `del`
  - `exec`
  - `from`
  - `global`
  - `import`
  - `pass`
  - `print`
  - `raise`
  - `return`
- [Compound Statements](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html)

  - `class`
  - `def`
  - `elif`
  - `except`
  - `finally`
  - `try`
  - `while`
  - `with`
- Misc

  - `as` (only used as part of `from`, `import` and `with` statements, never on its own)
- Multiple kinds of uses:

  - `else` (can be part of an expression or a compound statement)
  - `for` (can be part of an expression or a compound statement)
  - `if` (can be part of an expression or a compound statement)
  - `in` (can be a binary operator, or paired with `for` in an expression or statement)

Comment: It's worth noting that in 3.3, ``from`` can be used as part of the ``yield`` statement - ``yield from some_generator``.

Comment: @Lattyware: Good point. Python 3 has a few other differences too: The literals `True`, `False`, `None` become keywords along with the `nonlocal` simple statement, while the `exec` and `print` statements cease to be keywords (and are replaced by functions of the same names).

Answer (score 0):

The [Python 2.7 Quick Reference](http://rgruet.free.fr/PQR27/PQR2.7.html) is probably in the vein of what you are looking for.

There's also the official [The Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/).

David Beazley's [Python Essential Reference, 4th Edition](http://www.dabeaz.com/per.html) book is probably the closest to what you are looking for, but only exists in book format (there's an ebook version).

Comment: I hope I'm not responding twice because my first attempt seems to have disappeared. Thanks for the quick reference because I didn't know about that one before and it looks pretty good. However, just like every other reference I've found, it perversely seems to not tell you how to use the keywords. If I'm wrong, can you point out where it tells you how to use the keyword *is*?

Comment: I don't think that exactly what you want actually exists, apart from the resources I have already mentioned. The closest I know of is the book I have added to my answer.